# UIView Animation block changes take place instantly?

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to Animate a UIImageView. Ive written the following code:

```
- (void)JumpAnimGoingDown {
NSLog(@"Started");
//Sets what happens in animation
self.character.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / WidthDivision, (self.character.center.y - (self.view.frame.size.height / 18)) + self.view.frame.size.height, (self.view.frame.size.height * 4) / 45, self.view.frame.size.height / 9);



[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear

                 animations:^{

                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // This block will execute when the animations finish

                     NSLog(@"Ended");

                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                 }
 ];
```

}

But when I call this Method in code the changes take place instantly:
http://gyazo.com/b34fd7fa84ea25ace5cd656b4068e6aa
This also happens with any other code I've tried to put in this animation block. Honestly I have no idea why this is happening or how to fix this so any help is greatly appreciated!

For those wondering i have tried changing the

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f
```

to

```
[UIImageView animateWithDuration:5.0f
```

and as this made no difference and in previous code I have written it has worked as shown then I don't think this is an issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any changes you want animating should be within the `animations` block.

```
- (void)JumpAnimGoingDown
{
    NSLog(@"Started");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear

                     animations:^{
                         //Sets what happens in animation
                         self.character.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width / WidthDivision, (self.character.center.y - (self.view.frame.size.height / 18)) + self.view.frame.size.height, (self.view.frame.size.height * 4) / 45, self.view.frame.size.height / 9);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         // This block will execute when the animations finish

                         NSLog(@"Ended");

                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
     ];
}
```